# Placing mesh particle on top of a diffferent mesh

Tags: modeling, mesh, particles, hair

There's an issue that i can't seem to solve with the hair particles. I have a mesh that I want it's bottom face to stick on the surface of another mesh. I've tried it on a flat surface and it seems to work just fine. But when I try it on a round surface it's giving me a totally different result. On a side note, I did check that the origin of the particle object is set to its original position.

Any thoughts?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why not use the particle system directly on the other mesh?

Comment: I tried, It still doesn't work, I think it probably has to do with normals.